# Setting icons before line number in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am assuming this should be done with gutterIconPath. I have tried the following code with no success:

```
const fontColorDecorator = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    text: "TODO:",
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#ffbd2a',
    overviewRulerColor: 'rgba(255,189,42,0.8)',
    dark: {
          gutterIconPath: path.join(__dirname, 'resources', 'dark', 'todo.png')
    }
});

 let ranges: vscode.Range[] = [];
 let singleRange: vscode.Range = new vscode.Range(startPos, endPos);
 ranges.push(singleRange);

activeEditor.setDecorations(fontColorDecorator, ranges);
```

[image]

**NOTES:** [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3642) issue tells that some time icons not appears in the High contrast theme. I am using Dark+(Default Dark) theme.

Comment: Is your `ranges` an array?

Comment: @tHeSiD: yes, its range. I have updated the code snippet. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not considering the fact that ***All the paths are referenced from the out directory*** . I have changed the gutterIconPath and the icon start appearing before line number.

Comment: Ha! Was just about to post this! Last question I just answered had the same issue :D

Comment: @tHeSiD: Thanks man. That single hint saved my life, wish I could give you more than one upvote.

Comment: Ohh it was you! Didn't notice! Happy to help! Gl with your extension!